# creating a table horizonally

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to create html table with horizontally  with json data

```
need ti display the table as 
name John
age  30
```

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  age: 30
};
//$('#geo_summary tbody').append(
Object.entries(user).reduce((res, row) => {
res.map(x => $('<td>').text(x))
//console.log(res);
});

//);
console.log(Object.entries(user).reduce((res, row) => {
 res.map(x => x)
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="geo_summary">
<tbody></tbody> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a combination of `Array.prototype.forEach` on the tuple returned by `Object.entries` and array destructuring:

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  age: 30
};

Object.entries(user).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  $('#geo_summary tbody').append(`<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${value}</td></tr>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="geo_summary">
<tbody></tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: `<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${value}</td></tr>`is not working for my application

Comment: how to do it in another way